# PHP class output correctly but exercise says is wrong

Tags: php

The code below output this phrases:

Hello, my name is Boring 12345. Nice to meet you! :-)

Hello, my name is Sasha Chirico. Nice to meet you! :-)

And it's look like ok, but when I click "Save & Submit Code" this one tell me: "Hey! Did you forget add my name as propoerty to the object?"

What's wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Reconstructing the Person Class</title>
  <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
<?php
class Person{
    public $isAlive = true;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname; 
    public $age;
    public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $age) {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
    public function greet(){
        return "Hello, my name is ".$this->firstname." ".$this->lastname.". Nice to meet you! :-)";
    }
}

$teacher = new Person("Boring", "12345", 12345);
$student = new Person("Sasha", "Chirico", 22);
echo $teacher->greet()."<br/><br/>";
echo $student->greet();

        ?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot-codecademy]

Comment: show your complete code there.

Comment: The only missing part is the <html> structure with the body and header, the php code are only this. But I'll add the missing part

Comment: What does the exercise state?

Comment: Class code seems OK...

Comment: "Hey! Did you forget add my name as propoerty to the object?" where is this message ?

Comment: Are you supposed to use `<p>` instead of `<br />` or something?

Comment: The <br/> it's only to break the line, to looks like pretty, but without it's the same, and the <p> it's not possibile, beacause it's output correctly and the problem are "Add the name as a property of the object"

Comment: @DeepKakkar It's Codecademy, the button that brings you to the next excercise

Comment: I'll add a screenshot too, so it's more clear for everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Reconstructing the Person Class</title>
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>

<?php

class Person {

public $isAlive = true;
public $firstname;
public $lastname;
public $age;

public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $age) {
                $this->firstname = $firstname;
                $this->lastname = $lastname;
                $this->age = $age;
            }



            public function greet() {
                return "Hello, my name is $this->firstname $this->lastname Nice to "
                        . " meet you";
            }

        }

        $teacher = new Person("boring", "12345", 12345);
        $student = new Person("Sasha", "Chirico", 22);

        echo $student->greet();
        echo $teacher->greet();

        ?>

</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to copy/paste this

Comment: I think I found out why. You have: 
$teacher = new Person("Boring", "12345", 12345); 
it should be
$teacher = new Person("boring", "12345", 12345);

Comment: That is probably stated in an earlier assignment.